# bull task in sailsjs not working?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, scheduled-tasks, bull.js

Well I (naively) tried to get bull working in a sails application: ultimatelly I wish to have a queue to which I can add/remove/check tasks based on incoming routes.

Now as I understand sails to create a queueing system that works globaly I would have to add this setup in bootstrap.js.

```
/**
 * Bootstrap
 * (sails.config.bootstrap)
 *
 * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before your Sails app gets lifted.
 * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model, run jobs, or perform some special logic.
 *
 * For more information on bootstrapping your app, check out:
 * https://sailsjs.com/config/bootstrap
 */
module.exports.bootstrap = function(done) {

  // It's very important to trigger this callback method when you are finished
  // with the bootstrap!  (otherwise your server will never lift, since it's waiting on the bootstrap)
  let Queue = require('bull');
  let q = new Queue('test queue');
  q.process(function(job, done){
    console.log("starting job");
    for(let i = 0; i<job.value; i+=1) {
      console.log(i);
    }
    done();
  });
  q.add({'value':10});
  global.DirectUpdateQueue = q;
  return done();

};
```

Given above code, sails launches perfectly fine, and in the routes I can see the `global.DirectUpdateQueue` existing.

What does however not work is that the queued tasks are executed. - I do not see any log in the console ("starting job" is expected at least). Nor does the code break whe nI put a breakpoint in the processing function.

So what is going on here?

EDIT: can this be due to me not having set up a (local) redis server? - I don't find any information on this subject but I expected/hoped bull.js to actually handle this server internally and (even more importantly) not be limited to a specific (OS) environment.

Comment: have you had success using bull.js outside of sails.js? I'm not familiar with bull.js at all, but their documentation seems to indicate that it's dependent on redis ("Requirements: Bull requires a Redis version greater than or equal to 2.8.18.")

Comment: @davepreston Using what server software then? I'd need something like express/sails incoming messages etc right? I can't just "run node" and connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, you have to make sure you have Redis installed on your server. 
When creating a queue, you can pass Redis config in my example below it's the default.

Then in bootsrap.js:

```
  var Queue = require('bull');
  var testQueue = new Queue('Website Queue', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379');
  testQueue.process(function(job, done){

    console.log('job started');

    setTimeout(function () {

        console.log('10 seconds later');
        console.log(job.data);

    }, 10000)

    done(); 
    });    

  global.testQueue = testQueue;
```

then from action/controller you can do this:

```
testQueue.add({'value':10});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must connect to a Redis server

```
var testQueue = new Queue('test', {
  redis: {
    port: 6379,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    password: 'secret'
  }
});
```

According to [the doc](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#queueadd) :

> If the queue is empty the job will be executed directly, otherwise it will be placed in the queue and executed as soon as possible.

To access data in job, use `job.data` object :

```
testQueue.process((job) => {
  console.log("job with data 'foo' :", job.data.foo);

  // example with Promise
  return asynchTreatment()
  .then(() => { console.log('treatment ok'); })
  .catch((err) => { console.log('treatment ko :', err); }
}).on('completed', (job, result) => {
  // Job completed with output result!
  console.log('result :', result);
});

testQueue.add({ foo : 'bar' });
```

**EDIT 1 :**

The doc says :

> It creates a new Queue that is persisted in Redis. Everytime the same queue is instantiated it tries to process all the old jobs that may exist from a previous unfinished session.

So if the server restart, you don't lose your jobs.

Comment: A Redis server is required to use bull. Where do you think bull is storing queue data ? Furthermore, it is quite simple to install one on your own.

Comment: Well I'd hoped it would just keep the data in memory. Mostly since if the server restarts/has a hickup it's required to empty the queue list anyways - the queue is also supposed to be "almost always empty" except for very short times when suddenly many things are added (typically 9 o'clock in the morning). So the setup of an extra redis server feels overkill.

Comment: Why an "extra" server ? You need at least one. And the queue is not empty on server restart.
I edited my answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Just use job.data.value in your for loop

```js
for(let i = 0; i<job.data.value; i+=1) {
  console.log(i);
}
```